# how to manipulate string in excel - VB?

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering if anyone could show me how to extrapolate 'http://www.nbc.com/xyz' and 'I love this show' from the following string in Excel - VB.

Thanks

```
<a href="http://www.nbc.com/xyz" >I love this show</a><IMG border=0 width=1 height=1 src="http://ad.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/show?id=Loe5O5QVFig&bids=261463.100016851&type=3&subid=0" >
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Sub Tester()
    '### add a reference to "Microsoft HTML Object Library" ###
    Dim odoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim el As Object
    Dim txt As String

    txt = "<a href=""http://www.nbc.com/xyz"" >I love this show</a>" & _
         "<IMG border=0 width=1 height=1 " & _
         "src=""http://ad.linksynergy.com/fs-bin/show?" & _
         "id=Loe5O5QVFig&bids=261463.100016851&type=3&subid=0"" >"

    odoc.body.innerHTML = txt

    Set el = odoc.getElementsByTagName("a")(0)
    Debug.Print el.innerText
    Debug.Print el.href

End Sub
```

Comment: Not bad, but I could process at least 1000 of these in the time it takes to load a single innerHTML :)

Comment: @ooo - well, I didn't make any claims about performance!  I would tend to prefer this method though, since it's a bit more forgiving than the regexp approach. For example, it will handle attributes regardless of whether they're single- or double-quoted.

Comment: +1 clever method. @ooo While I'm a regexp fan I am wary of doing so with html.

Comment: @TimWilliams - I've just re-read my earlier comment and it comes across as really snooty. It wasn't intended to be!

Comment: @ooo - no problem. No offense taken!

Answer (score 0):

Once way is using regular expressions. Another way is using Split to split the strings on various delimiters Eg

```
Option Explicit

Sub splitMethod()
Dim Str As String

    Str = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value
    Debug.Print Split(Str, """")(1)
    Debug.Print Split(Split(Str, ">")(1), "</a")(0)

End Sub

Sub RegexMethod()
Dim Str As String
Dim oRegex As Object
Dim regexArr As Object
Dim rItem As Object

    'Assumes Sheet1.Range("A1").Value holds example string
    Str = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value

    Set oRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With oRegex
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "(href=""|>)(.+?)(""|</a>)"
        Set regexArr = .Execute(Str)

        'No lookbehind so replace unwanted chars
        .Pattern = "(href=""|>|""|</a>)"
        For Each rItem In regexArr
            Debug.Print .Replace(rItem, vbNullString)
        Next rItem
    End With
End Sub

'Output:
'http://www.nbc.com/xyz
'I love this show
```

This matches `href="` or `>` at the start of the string, `"` or `</a>` at the end of the string with any character (except \n newline) in between  `(.+?)`